# laravel 10 worker ends up with Broken pipe error

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

Laravel 10 worker sometimes ends with error.

CODE:

```
Artisan::queue('task:post_server', [
            'db' => $db,
            'model' => $model,
            'server' => $server,
            'post' => $post,
        ]);
Process::timeout(600)->start('php ' . base_path('artisan') . ' queue:work');
```

ERROR:

```
[2023-09-08 07:54:55] local.ERROR: fwrite(): Write of 65 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fwrite(): Write of 65 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Output/StreamOutput.php:74)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Phrity\\Util\\ErrorHandler->Phrity\\Util\\{closure}(8, 'fwrite(): Write...', '/var/www/html/v...', 74)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Output/StreamOutput.php(74): fwrite(Resource id #2, '  2023-09-08 07...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Output/Output.php(145): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\StreamOutput->doWrite('  2023-09-08 07...', false)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Style/OutputStyle.php(51): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\Output->write(Array, false, 0)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Style/SymfonyStyle.php(386): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\OutputStyle->write('  <fg=gray>2023...', false, 0)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/OutputStyle.php(49): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle->write(Array, false, 0)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(205): Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle->write('  <fg=gray>2023...')
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(176): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->writeOutput(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), 'success')
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(421): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Events\\JobProcessed))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(249): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Events\\{closure}('Illuminate\\\\Queu...', Array)
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(667): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->dispatch('Illuminate\\\\Queu...')
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(441): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->raiseAfterJobEvent('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(389): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(176): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(138): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(121): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(662): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(208): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(326): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(178): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1081): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(320): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(174): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(200): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#29 {main}
"} 
[2023-09-08 07:56:29] local.ERROR: fwrite(): Write of 65 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fwrite(): Write of 65 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Output/StreamOutput.php:74)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Phrity\\Util\\ErrorHandler->Phrity\\Util\\{closure}(8, 'fwrite(): Write...', '/var/www/html/v...', 74)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Output/StreamOutput.php(74): fwrite(Resource id #2, '  2023-09-08 07...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Output/Output.php(145): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\StreamOutput->doWrite('  2023-09-08 07...', false)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Style/OutputStyle.php(51): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\Output->write(Array, false, 0)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Style/SymfonyStyle.php(386): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\OutputStyle->write('  <fg=gray>2023...', false, 0)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/OutputStyle.php(49): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle->write(Array, false, 0)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(205): Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle->write('  <fg=gray>2023...')
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(176): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->writeOutput(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), 'success')
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(421): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Events\\JobProcessed))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(249): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Events\\{closure}('Illuminate\\\\Queu...', Array)
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(667): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->dispatch('Illuminate\\\\Queu...')
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(441): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->raiseAfterJobEvent('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(389): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(176): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(138): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(121): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(662): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(208): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(326): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(178): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1081): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(320): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(174): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(200): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#29 {main}
"}
```

Comment: it look like you don't have write permission on directory, Please check directory permissions.

Answer (score 0):

My laravel websocket server did not work.